# PHP OOP Login/Register System

Tags: php, pdo

First of all I would like to thank Codecourse for the tutorial.
Everything works a treat but i would like to display the errors into my table td.
Maybe a dumb question but I'm a beginner and tried working it out my self with no luck

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validate->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

            if($login) {
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            } else 
                echo "Incorrect username or password";

        } else {
            foreach($validate->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action='' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><!-- display errors here --></td>
                    <td><!-- and/or here --></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for='username'>Username</label></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='username' id='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for='password'>Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' id='password'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><label for='remember'><input type='checkbox' name='remember' id='remember'>Remember me</label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>'></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='Login'></td>
                </tr>
            </table>   
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just move the foreach looping over the errors down to where you want to show them.

Comment: Assign all the errors to a variable ($error_messages) and echo it where ever you want.

Comment: @JimL - I don't think it is that simple, we'll have to add the errors in that loop to an array, and then do an additional foreach loop

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix why? I haven't seen the full code / codecourse tutorial, but after what's posted here it seems like it would be no problem just moving the loop.

Comment: @JimL - mainly because you would have to check that the if conditions pass to create the `$validate` object.  So you would be doing additional and unnessacery logical checks.  It also makes the errors less portable, because you are relying on their source, for example, you couldn't inject a message in there anywhere else if you wanted to.

Comment: True, you would also have to move the initialization of $validate to the top. Depending on the use case I'd still just go with what's there already. Prepping it to support additional error messages by creating another array/loop feels cluttery in this case.

Comment: Yea there is a good use case for portability right in the question, `echo "Incorrect username or password";`  This can just be added into a separate array and output the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$errors = array(); //storage variable

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validate->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

            if($login) {
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            } else 
                $errors[] = "Incorrect username or password"; //add other errors in too!

        } else {
            foreach($validate->errors() as $error) {
                $errors[] = $error; //add error to storage
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action='' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><!-- display errors here --></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php foreach( $errors as $error ) : ?>
                            <?php echo $error; // output ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for='username'>Username</label></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='username' id='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for='password'>Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' id='password'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><label for='remember'><input type='checkbox' name='remember' id='remember'>Remember me</label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>'></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='Login'></td>
                </tr>
            </table>   
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just store them in a variable, and then output them where you want, pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Push all of the errors to an array, and then display all of those errors in your table.

Array_push:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Array_map:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Example:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d6749095ed20a995ec8697ef203d164f